# Breakpoints in multiple files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a Python project with multiple files/modules, that I'm trying to debug. I have the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed, and I put a bunch of breakpoints in - some in the current file and some in another file/module. Breakpoints in the current file are working fine, however, the breakpoints in other file(s) are not. Is there a step I'm missing in setting the debugger up? Couldn't find anything on Google for this specific problem, the tutorials only show debugging in one file and that is working fine. If I try to right click and go to the definition of any function in another module, that also works fine so the project is aware of the multiple modules (I have the whole directory open in VS Code), the breakpoints don't.

Comment: Same question. Expecting the answer to be simple, a setting, preference somewhere. An addition to `launch.json`. Surely a common use case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ran into the same issue. In case you still need to know, this is how I resolved it.

1. Create a workspace in vscode
2. Add the folders you want into the workspace with all the files you need. We need to do this to create the launch.json file
3. Click on the Debug Icon or Ctrl+Shift+D
4. Click the gear icon in the debug sidebar at the top. It will say open launch.json
5. If one is not created, it will automatically create it for and it should look like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

6. Add in **justMyCode**, but set to false

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

7. Save and start debugging. You should be able to step into other modules now.

A screenshot of what the debug screen configuration should now look like:
[image: Python debug configuration]

You can create different configs if you don't want to debug other modules or do things as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the new version. I installed 2018.9.1 and it works.